# why does junction table of many to many relation in sql implemet both foreign key as primary key?

Tags: mysql, join, many-to-many

```
CREATE TABLE Books(
        BookID SMALLINT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
        BookTitle VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL,
        Copyright YEAR NOT NULL
     )




CREATE TABLE Authors(
        AuthID SMALLINT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
        AuthFN VARCHAR(20),
        AuthMN VARCHAR(20),
        AuthLN VARCHAR(20)
     )


CREATE TABLE AuthorBook(
        AuthID SMALLINT NOT NULL,
        BookID SMALLINT NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY (AuthID, BookID),
        FOREIGN KEY (AuthID) REFERENCES Authors (AuthID),
        FOREIGN KEY (BookID) REFERENCES Books (BookID)
    )
```

here junction table  is authorbook
why primary key is (authorid,bookid) is used

why not have a seperate table id and make it primary key?

Comment: You can do it either way. When wider datatypes are in place, such as varchars, a thin PK is preferable for scaling. For special use cases of compositing, you certainly need to have the int id as seen [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38340726) in special use cases.

Comment: Why add a surrogate key to what are already surrogate keys?  Unless the resolution table is to be a master to another <set of> detail, there is no reason to add yet another meaningless key to the table.  As an industry we've gone crazy with surrogates, IMHO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> why not have a separate table id and make it primary key?

Because you would then need to create a unique index on `AuthID`, `BookID` to ensure that duplicate pairs of `(AuthID, BookID)` are not inserted into this table.

Having many indexes usually slows down inserts and updates and increases the size of the data on disk. BY having a composite primary key, that problem is minimized.

Having said that, certain ORMs most notably [Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/), does not support multi colum primary keys. Therefor Django's [ManyToManyField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/) does indeed have a sequential primary key along with a unque key on `(AuthID, BookID)` - exactly the alternative method that you asked about.

Comment: Please join me in [Campaigns](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95290/campaigns) to try to work on `mysql` Docs. Thx e4c5

Comment: gladly will do @Drew